# In the winforms designer, can I turn off the annoying double click -> code behind event handler creation?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

Most of the time this is handy, but sometimes I want this turned off. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Why? If you turn it off, double-clicking will do nothing, and if it does nothing, there's no point double-clicking, ergo why not just stop double-clicking?

Comment: It is a legitimate question, accidental double-clicks when using the designer are not unusual.  The workaround is not very obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally double click more times than I want to.

Comment: I just needed a new mouse. It was double clicking on me randomly when I single click.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Because some of us have tremor disorders and find it physically difficult, sometimes even impossible, to single click without accidentally double clicking. I've got half a mind to sue Microsoft under the ADA to force them to add the option.

Comment: @JoshuaPech: that's a valid point, thanks for raising it.

Comment: This problem persists with Visual Studio 17.5.3. All of the sudden the designer became super sensitive and does the "double-click" to create events even when I single click! My work around, for now, is to use Right Click to select components in the form design. Changing Windows Mouse settings does not change Visual Studio's sensitivity for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no option for this.  The workaround is simple, just type Ctrl+Z and click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Right+Click is a work around that allows you to select components in the form design without *accidental* double-click creating unwanted event code and without switching from design view to code view.

... until you can replace the mouse B-)